# JQuery UI - Can't get datepicker to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

The question is very simple. I have everything included properly, but the datepicker just won't show up. I have the script added in my html head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'); ?>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery.ui.core.css'); ?>">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url('css/jquery.ui.datepicker.css'); ?>">
```

Than the date picker code...

```
<input type="text" name="date" id="date">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#date" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-m-d" });  
    });
</script>
```

And that's it. There's no date picker or anything on that text input. Also no error... :(

Comment: Have you loaded the jQuery UI's css file?

Comment: It's used for styling elements created by UI library. Without it you should style the elements yourself, madness.

Comment: I've been there, read it - didn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

include jquery before  jquery ui.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

working code

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
   $( "#date" ).datepicker();
 });
</script>
```

Date:

Comment: That's quite logical. I edited my question so it will be more clear.

Comment: Your code snippet saved my ass. But I have no idea what was doing wrong.